# How to deal with missing values in the survey data to perform Paired sample t test

Tags: missing-data, hypothesis-testing

I have a dataset where I have 100 respondents. Each respondent has to give response on service quality of Health care equipment. Is it  providing efficient services to the patients?
We have two columns 'Expected service quality' and 'Perceived service quality'. We will perform this equation= Service quality=Expected-Perceived to see if the service quality is positive or negative. If the difference is negative, it states we need improvement in that area.
Now the problem is the two columns have many missing values and I have to perform paired t test on the data. In the first column there are 15 missing values and in 2nd I have 56 missing values. How do I deal with these missing values?

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot use these data points for this test, you have to use only the data points for which both variables have a value. This will make the sample smaller, so it's less likely to result in a significant difference.

Comment: Can't we replace all the missing values of one variable with its mean/median?

Comment: @pinky, you can, but you would be introducing a serious bias in the data so the result of the test wouldn't be reliable. Basically it's like pretending that there is some data where there isn't any, doing this is similar to adding 1000 data points made of the mean of the values: it might change the result of the test but it's meaningless.

Comment: Now I have removed all the missing values and ran descriptive statistics and Shapiro test( for normality). From Shapiro test, I saw that the data is not normal so I wanted to conduct Wilcoxon test instead of paired t test. From the descriptive statistics output , I saw that medians are  equal. But after running Wilcoxon, I saw that p value <0.05 which rejects null and states that there is some difference in medians of the two groups. Now my descriptive output states medians of two groups are equal but my wilcoxon output shows medians of the two groups are not equal. why is this discrepancy?

Comment: @pinky depends what is "descriptive statistics output"?

Comment: Descriptive statistics output of two groups:1  2 
   
Mean 6.639344262 Mean 6.027322404
Standard Error 0.050180708 Standard Error 0.085899632
Median 7 Median 7
Mode 7 Mode 7
Standard Deviation 0.960013474 Standard Deviation 1.643356718
Sample Variance 0.92162587 Sample Variance 2.700621304
Kurtosis 19.5723003 Kurtosis 2.914502094
Skewness -4.100111747 Skewness -1.928436144
Range 6 Range 6
Minimum 1 Minimum 1
Maximum 7 Maximum 7
Sum 2430 Sum 2206
Count 366 Count 366

Comment: > wilcox.test(A$1, A$2, paired=TRUE)

 Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  A$1 and A$2
V = 6505, p-value = 1.919e-13
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Comment: @pinky oh wait a minute, I didn't read your problem carefully: a significant Wilcoxon test means that the two samples are from two different distributions. There is no contradiction: it's totally possible that the samples are from different distributions and have the same median value. Example: [1,5,10,15,20] and [9,10,10,10,99] are certainly different distributions but have the same median. Btw the other statistics are quite different.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not understand. What should the conclusion be for my above question? Do I have to go by p value of Wilcoxon and conclude that medians of the two groups are different?

Comment: The medians are not different but the distributions are different. There's no discrepancy, these two facts are compatible. Your main conclusion should be that the distributions are different, the fact that the medians are identical doesn't really matter.

Comment: so does that mean that since the distributions are different, the 2 groups have different values? In my analysis, I need to give a conclusion if expected and perceived values are different or are they equal to null hypothesis.

Comment: @pinky ok, it's difficult to explain significance tests in just a comment, so I encourage you to read about it. In general the idea of a significance test like Wilcoxon is to determine if the differences between two samples are just due to chance or not. The fact that you obtain a *statistically significant* difference proves that there is a "real" difference between expected and perceived values, i.e. it's not due to chance. Of course some of the values in one sample might be equal to some values in the other sample, the statistical difference is about the data as a whole, not the ...

Comment: ... individual values. Probably an important part of your conclusion would be about the *direction* of this difference: in general, is it "expected value < perceived value" or "perceived value < expected value"? Apparently your mean for one sample is 6.6 and 6.03 for the other sample but I don't know which one is which.